# how to solve temporary redirect in magento 2.4.3

Tags: redirect, page, http-error-500, 301-redirect, magento2.4.3.p1

I am the owner of the jewelry site when I run a Site audit from Semrush I get 944 temporary redirects, and I do not know how to solve temporary redirects in Magento 2.4.3
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through a lot of hardship doing so. Steps to follow

1. Go to Marketing > Url Rewrites.
2. Find the url paths one by one and change to redirect type No.
3. Check the url with URL checker.